# Publish message with multiple routing keys

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

I am using a topic exchange and have set up the bindings between the queues and the exchange. I need to publish a single message to one or more queues. Doing this requires one or more routing keys. However I am not sure how to send multiple routing keys with the message.

For example having 3 queues:

```
"Queue1" with binding Key: "msg.orders"
"Queue2" with binding Key: "msg.accounts"
"Queue3" with binding Key: "msg.clients"
```

Now I want to publish a message to Queue1 and Queue2 so therefore I need to use routing key "msg.orders" and "msg.accounts" but how can this be done? Is it possible to use any SQL like operator like "&&" ?

I have also looked into Headers exchange but this does not allow me to use the (#) and (*) wildcards. Basically it does not use a routing key it works via message properties.

I also do not want to declare new exchanges and set bindings each time I have a message which need to got o specific queues

I am looking for something in between where I can "publish to many" using routing key wildcards and also specify the which queue to publish

Comment: A single message can only have a single routing key. Queues, however, can have multiple binding to exchanges with their own (different) routing key. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am doing a pub/sub type pattern where I have 1 exchange of type Topic and I have multiple Queues. Each queue have binding keys to the same exchange but with different routing keys as shown above. Now I want to publish a message that will go into Queue 1 and Queue 2. I know we can use the star (*) to point to all queues but when I want to point to 2 specific queues can I have multiple routing key in my message ?

Comment: My alternative would be using this [Sender-selected Distribution](https://www.rabbitmq.com/sender-selected.html) but do not wish to fall down this route and use this extension

Comment: Seems you're fixated on the topic exchange where you've made some assumptions doing your configuration, and you're not broadening the analysis sufficiently. What I mean by that is, can you clarify in your problem description (ideally updating your question, not in comments) what the publisher knows as to where the message needs to go? Coming back to @gunr2171 comment, you can for example have multiple bindings between an exchange and a queue. Or you could go towards [headers exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-headers).